# 2 Column CSS Floated Layout

Tags: css

Pulling my hair out with this simple CSS layout. I have a 2-column fixed layout with a header and a footer all contained in a wrapper. I need the "left" background area in the CSS to automatically extend to the footer when the content in the "right" column is longer (as in the attached. I have tried "height: 100%;" and this does not work.

Can anyone help?

http://eyes-open.com/index.html

Comment: I've been watching your progress on your linked site, I'm glad you've found a solution! The reverse of what I put really :) (contents having the bg image and the sidebar pushing the box)

Gj!

Comment: I hope you return to tick my answer as the correct one JayOh...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah this problem is annoying.

Another solution would be to have the container div the colour you want your nav to be, then make the contents to be another colour:

```
<style>
#page { background-color:blue; width: 996px; etc }
#contents { background-color:red; etc }
</style>
<div id="page">
     <div id="sidebar">
    </div>
    <div id="contents">
   </div>
</div>
```

ends up looking like:

```
 _____________________
|   |                 |
|   |                 |
|   |                 |
|   |                 |
|___|                 |
|___|_________________|
```

with the divs, but the colour of the background "page" will be on the left, and the background of the content will be on the right

I hope that helps. This suffers from when the right is smaller than the left :(

edit:

you can also use bg images if you so wish in this format. This is something that is very awkward to do in html/css and you just need to play until you get a solution which fits you. This took me days to research for my site :(

Answer (score 0):

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/

Make a fake bg image and repeat it vertically down on the container of both. make sure the container clears the floats.

Comment: What happens when images are disabled?

Comment: Define images. Regular good ole images? Bg images through css disabling?

Comment: @Josh K: -1 to you if I could (for your down-vote)!  If people turn off images then they aren't going to see his page it all it's beautiful glory, it's that simple.  +1 mender

Comment: @meder: Either. Disabling images will remove backgrounds as well as "regular good ole" images. You have to make sure that the content on your site has a fallback for images being disabled. Placing a dark background image under white text will cause major issues (i.e. can't read anything).

Comment: @Josh K - Then one would simply specify a bg color on the container as a fallback? I thought that was assumed/ a given.

Answer (score 0):

This site:

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-2-column-left-menu.htm

Has some excellent examples of all kinds of such layouts, that are very nicely done and (relatively) clean.  They're what I've used in the past, and they work very nicely.  They're a bit complex, but they work, and this is a notorious problem in CSS that isn't solved easily.  The solution above is the best, cleanest, and most reliable solution I've found.